# check if point in On route or near route GeoTools

Tags: java, coordinates, point, radius

I have assetRoute_TB collection in the mongoDb in which i have set coordinates for the route of the vehicle, now i have point of the moving vehicle meaning point(lat lng) and i need to check if the point is on route or near route like in radius of 1 mile, in the listed Aggregation i am extracting the route coordinates from the SourceWayPoint Array by using Object id of the document that match the vechile route.

```
public boolean withInSource(MongoCollection<Document> assetRouteCollection, Double latitude, Double longitude, ArrayList<String> objectIds ){
    for (String object : objectIds) {
        ProjectionOperation Project = project("SourceWayPoint");

        Aggregation Ags = newAggregation(
                match(Criteria.where("_id").is(object)),
                Project);
        MongoAssetRoute route = mongoTemplate.aggregate(Ags,"AssetRoute_TB",MongoAssetRoute.class).getUniqueMappedResult();
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: i want to create route from the coordinates that i got from the SourceWayPoint and check if the lat lng that i got from the device is on the SourceWayPoint Route or is in the radius of 1 mile

Comment: You need to show the code you have tried so far and tell us what is going wrong